# How to calculate a path from [0,0] to [M, N] with min sum in a matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

I need to calculate a path from [0,0] to [M, N] with min-sum in a matrix moving only right or down?

I found such link https://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-minimum-path-sum-java/ but Dynamic Programming option is not clear at all.

I was trying to implement it on my own with BFS algorithm but it is a slow solution

```
public int minPathSum(final int[][] grid) {
        if (grid.length == 1 && grid[0].length == 1) {
            return grid[0][0];
        }
        final int[][] moves = {new int[]{1, 0}, new int[]{0, 1}};
        final Queue<int[]> positions = new ArrayDeque<>();
        final Queue<Integer> sums = new ArrayDeque<>();
        positions.add(new int[]{0, 0});
        sums.add(grid[0][0]);
        int minSum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while (!positions.isEmpty()) {
            final int[] point = positions.poll();
            final int sum = sums.poll();
            for (final int[] move : moves) {
                final int x = point[0] + move[0];
                final int y = point[1] + move[1];
                if (x == grid.length - 1 && y == grid[0].length - 1) {
                    minSum = Math.min(minSum, sum);
                } else if (x > -1 && y > -1 && x < grid.length && y < grid[0].length) {
                    positions.add(new int[]{x, y});
                    sums.add(sum + grid[x][y]);
                }
            }
        }
        return minSum + grid[grid.length - 1][grid[0].length - 1];
    }
```

Could you please explain and if possible provide how will you solve it?

Comment: Line between those points is diagonal of the rectangle. So your path will be half the perimeter (circumference) of this rectangle. Am I right?

Comment: the easiest way would probably be a recursive function, that calculates the min of the two possibilities in recursion. How big is the matrix going to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by how you could implement a breadth first search but have trouble understanding the dynamic formulation here, which to me seems simpler :)

This is pretty much the classic dynamic programming problem. Arriving at any cell, `solution[y][x]`, except the first, has at most two predecessors: `option 1` and `option 2`. Assume that we knew the optimal solution for reaching each of those, which edge would we choose? Clearly the better of the two options!

Slightly more formally, if `M` holds the given values:

```
solution[0][0] = M[0][0]

// only one choice along
// the top horizontal and
// left vertical

solution[0][x] =
  M[0][x] + solution[0][x - 1]

solution[y][0] =
  M[y][0] + solution[y - 1][0]

// two choices otherwise:
// the best of option 1 or 2

solution[y][x] =
  M[y][x] + min(
    solution[y][x - 1],
    solution[y - 1][x]
  )
```

We can see that we can create an appropriate routine, with `for` loops for example, to visit the cells of our `solution` matrix in "bottom-up" order since each cell's value depends on one or two predecessors that we would have already calculated.

JavaScript code:

```js
function show(M){
  let str = '';
  for (let row of M)
    str += JSON.stringify(row) + '\n';
  console.log(str);
}

function f(M){
  console.log('Input:\n');
  show(M);
  
  let solution = new Array();
  for (let i=0; i<M.length; i++)
    solution.push(new Array(M[0].length).fill(Infinity));
    
  solution[0][0] = M[0][0];

  // only one choice along
  // the top horizontal and
  // left vertical
  
  for (let x=1; x<M[0].length; x++)
    solution[0][x] =
      M[0][x] + solution[0][x - 1];

  for (let y=1; y<M.length; y++)
    solution[y][0] =
      M[y][0] + solution[y - 1][0];
      
  console.log('Solution borders:\n');
  show(solution);

  // two choices otherwise:
  // the best of option 1 or 2

  for (let y=1; y<M.length; y++)
    for (let x=1; x<M[0].length; x++)
      solution[y][x] =
        M[y][x] + Math.min(
          solution[y][x - 1],
          solution[y - 1][x]
        );
        
  console.log('Full solution:\n');
  show(solution);
  
  return solution[M.length-1][M[0].length-1];
}

let arr = [];
arr[0] = [0, 7, -7];
arr[1] = [6, 7, -8];
arr[2] = [1, 2, 0];

console.log(f(arr));
```

Comment: So do you mean simply choose the min on each step? What one of the cells contains a negative value? What if the matrix is: arr[0] = {0, 7, -7}, arr[1] = {6, 7, -8}, arr[2] = {1, 2, 0} ?

Comment: @Pavel the question says to find a "path...with min-sum." What's the problem with negative numbers?

Comment: Your solution doesn't support it because next after a min() cell can be a positive value, but next after a greater cell can be a negative value

Comment: @Pavel I don't understand. Can you give an example of how it fails? The formulation is pure math.

Comment: arr[0] = {0, 7, -7}, arr[1] = {6, 7, -8}, arr[2] = {1, 2, 0}

Comment: the expected route is: 0 -> 7 -> -7 -> -8 -> 0 and expected sum is -8; as I understand from you solution the route would be 0 -> 6 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0

Comment: @Pavel No, I think you maybe misunderstand how the dynamic program works. We will calculate the optimal (in this case minimum) sum up to and including each cell in the solution matrix. Cell [0][2] will be 0 since there is only one choice along the top horizontal. I leave it to you to fill the matrix. Then check the value at [2][2].

Comment: @Pavel sure. But are you having trouble calculating the solution matrix for your example? The logic for that is provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The path to reach (m, n) must be through one of the 2 cells: (m-1, n) or (n-1, m). So minimum sum to reach (m, n) can be written as “minimum of the 2 cells plus sum[m][n]”.

```
minSum(m, n) = min (minSum(m-1, n-1), minSum(m-1, n)) + sums[m][n]
```

Comment: So do you mean simply choose the min on each step? What one of the cells contains a negative value? What if the matrix is: arr[0] = {0, 7, -7}, arr[1] = {6, 7, -8}, arr[2] = {1, 2, 0} ?